# Is it possible to make Date.now more readable in Mongoose when using it in the schema definition?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I use a schema as such:

```
  timestamp:  { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now },
```

which works fine, however in the DB it looks like this:

```
 "timestamp": {
        "$date": "2020-06-20T06:05:36.487Z"
    },
```

Which I might assume is

```
June 20, 2020 @ 6:05:36 seconds and 487 milliseconds
```

Where T might stand for Time ... but what does Z stand for?

Is my interpretation correct and is there a way to format it so it is more readable?

Answer (score 0):

The `T` is there just as a seperator, doesn't really mean anything. The `Z` means zero timezone so it is zero hours off from UTC. If it was 1 hour up from UTC it would be `+1`.